# I'm trying to configure behat and seeing an error - failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/behat

Tags: autoloader, behat

PHP Warning:  require_once(behat/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/behat on line 23
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'behat/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/bin/pear:/usr/lib/php:/Users/steve/perforce/') in /usr/bin/behat on line 23

Any ideas what might be causing this??

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

do you have the file at one of the following places
:/usr/bin/pear/behat/autoload.php OR :/usr/lib/php/behat/autoload.php: OR /Users/steve/perforce/behat/autoload.php

I am sure it is not there. if it is some where else like BASE_PATH.'my_folder'
add this path to include paths
like this

```
set_include_path(BASE_PATH.'my_folder',get_include_path());
```

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a broken installation. I would suggest you install behat with composer, if you want it globally installed then run

`$ composer global require behat/behat`

Then make sure you add the composer path to your `$PATH` variable.

Its much easier to work with behat as a local dependency of your project. I am not sure if you are using it for a PHP project but if you are then i'd recommend not to install it globally, instead in your composer.json file add it as a dev dependency:

```
{
  "require-dev": {
    "behat/behat": "~3.0"
  }
}
```

Then run `composer update` to get it installed locally. You can then access it by running `vendor/bin/behat`.

From personal experience, installing behat globally can give you issues because of other local libraries you may need per project basis. This may have been resolved now but I had issues when one local project behat dependency differed from another projects.