# Installing behat on a Symfony 2.0 project using deps - what versions?

Tags: behat, symfony-2.0

I have a legacy Symfony 2.0 project (version 2.0.11 to be precise) to which I'd like to add behat tests.  As it's Symfony 2.0, it uses the `deps` vendor system rather than composer.  I'm not in a position to upgrade the Symfony version or switch to composer at the moment.

I attempted to install behat using the following deps settings:

```
[Mink]
    target=/Behat/Mink
    git=git://github.com/Behat/Mink.git
    version=v1.3.3

[MinkBundle]
    target=/Behat/MinkBundle
    git=git://github.com/Behat/MinkBundle.git

[BehatBundle]
    target=/Behat/BehatBundle
    git=git://github.com/Behat/BehatBundle.git

[Gherkin]
    target=/Behat/Gherkin
    git=git://github.com/Behat/Gherkin.git
    version=v2.1.1

[Behat]
    target=/Behat/Behat
    git=git://github.com/Behat/Behat.git
    version=v2.3.5

[Goutte]
    target=/Goutte
    git=git://github.com/fabpot/Goutte.git
```

(Yes, I know that the BehatBundle etc are outdated, but it looked like I'd need these outdated versions given that I'm using deps and sf2.0.)

When I run `vendor/Behat/Behat/bin/behat`, I then get the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832761/im-trying-to-configure-behat-and-seeing-an-error-failed-to-open-stream-no-su):

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(behat/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sam/wo-code/PersonaBubble/vendor/Behat/Behat/bin/behat on line 23
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'behat/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/sam/wo-code/PersonaBubble/vendor/Behat/Behat/bin/behat on line 23
```

I realised that behat 2.3.5 doesn't actually have an `autoload.php` file.  I looked through Behat's tags on Github and realised that [2.1.3](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/tree/v2.1.3) was the latest version which had an `autoload.php` (actually `autoload.php.dist`, though every earlier version also had `autoload.php.dist` rather than `autoload.php`, so I assumed that this was it).

I therefore changed my behat version number in `deps` to `v2.1.3`, deleted my vendors and re-installed.  The behat command had then changed, so I ran:

```
php vendor/Behat/Behat/bin/behat.php
```

I now saw [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902132/when-running-bin-behat-i-get-a-class-not-found-error):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Application' not found in /home/sam/wo-code/PersonaBubble/vendor/Behat/Behat/src/Behat/Behat/Console/BehatApplication.php on line 26
```

**Does anyone know what the correct versions of behat etc are that I should use to get it working with Symfony 2.0 and deps?**  Or is there some other step that I'm missing.

PS I ended up running behat via PHAR (although this [had other problems](https://github.com/Behat/Symfony2Extension/issues/9) so I abandoned it as not worth it).  However, I really want to know how to do it via standard vendors install, hence this post.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not in a position to upgrade the Symfony version or switch to
>   composer at the moment.

I understand what you say but example below might give you a bit of hint I hope! I hope it helps a bit.

I'm sharing what I have been using for all my Symfony2 projects. Behat+Mink+Selenium

**CONPOSER:**

You need certain versions so that eveyone use same versions of everthing.

**mySymfonyProject/composer.json:**

```
"require": {
    "behat/behat": "2.5.*@stable",
    "behat/behat-bundle": "1.0.0",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "1.1.2",
    "behat/mink": "1.5.0",
    "behat/mink-extension": "~1.3",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "1.1.1",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "1.0.9"
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

**BEHAT**

**mySymfonyProject/behat.yml:**

```
default:
    context:
        class: FeatureContext
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            mink_driver: true
            kernel:
                env: test
                debug: true
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: 'http://mysymfonyproject.local/app_test.php/'
            javascript_session: selenium2
            browser_name: firefox
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
    paths:
        features: %behat.paths.base%/src
        bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/Context
```

**SELENIUM**

Download into your project. It is [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), **make sure** you download 2.43.1 version which is in the middle of the page.

Run it: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar`

**CONTEXT FEATURE**

**mySymfonyProject/src/Site/CommonBundle/Features/Context/FeatureContext.php**

```
<?php

namespace Site\CommonBundle\Features\Context;

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements KernelAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * Hold Symfony kernel object.
     *
     * @var object Kernel Object.
     */
    protected $kernel;

    /**
     * Helps to use doctrine and entity manager.
     *
     * @param KernelInterface $kernelInterface Interface for getting Kernel.
     */
    public function setKernel(KernelInterface $kernelInterface)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernelInterface;
    }

    //And your own methods
}
```

**TESTS**

When you have feature files you can run them like this (this runs all in one go. for more info read behat doc):

```
bin/behat @SiteCommonBundle
```